# Lenovo S110 netbook screen resolution Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, display, resolution

I am still stuck with 800x600 resolution. Here is the output of lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0bf2 (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 0be2 (rev 09)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 02)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 02)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 2 (rev 02)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 3 (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1d.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1d.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 02)
00:1d.3 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 02)
00:1d.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev e2)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation NM10 Family LPC Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH7 Family SATA AHCI Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 02)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 8176 (rev 01)
```

Also, I tried modifying /usr/lib/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf to fix this problem, but still does not work:

```
Section "Monitor"
        Identifier      "Monitor0"
        VendorName  "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName   "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier      "Screen0"
    Monitor     "Monitor0"       
        Device          "Card0"
             SubSection      "Display"
                Viewport        0 0
                Depth           1
                Modes           "1024x768"
             EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
            Viewport    0 0
            Depth       4
            Modes       "1024x768"
        EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
            Viewport    0 0
            Depth       8
            Modes       "1024x768"
        EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
            Viewport    0 0
            Depth       15
            Modes       "1024x768"
        EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
            Viewport    0 0
            Depth       16
            Modes       "1024x768"
        EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
            Viewport    0 0
            Depth       24
            Modes       "1024x768"
        EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Device"
   Identifier   "Card0"
   Driver   "vesa"
   VendorName   "Intel Corporation Device"
EndSection
```

I'm using Gnome. System > Preference > Monitor screen resolution sticks to 800x600. What am I going to do?

Answer (score -1):

You can try forcing xrandr by manually adding mode to it.

Comment: … and how does one do that? Can you expand your answer, please?